# Paypal IPN for Mobile Payments Library

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I use [Paypal Mobile Payments Library](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf) for my payments at the Android. For verification i use [IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)

When i do buying from web application or use [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session) i receive good purchase and status "VERIFED" for it.
But when i receive callback after buying from my Android i receive status "INVALID" though at the client purchase is completed and money move from buyer to marchant.

For purchase from my web application and IPN Simulator i have similar parameters such as:
http://ompldr.org/vZDVxdw

But for mobile purchase i have some strange parameters as:
http://ompldr.org/vZDVxeQ

Where can i got parameters payment_request_date, fees_payer, ipn_notification_url etc from?
Where cam i have got any mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad callback (IPN) from Paypal. It include false parameters.
I think there is some problem with [setIpnUrl(String IPNURL)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf) for the Android.

I try to use static IPN URL set in the [Profile in the seller Accaunt](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup) and it have started to work for me!